# mongodb- indexes on list fields for $all queries

Tags: mongodb, indexing, pymongo

I am making an application using pymongo wrapper for which my schema is like:

```
{
    _id: <some_id>,
    name: <some_name>,
    my_tags: [<list_of_tags>]
}
```

Now I want to return those entries which falls under the user specified tags. For example,
I want to have entries where my_tags should be atleast ["college", "USA", "engineering"]. For that I read $all construct can be used. Now what I want to know is, would it be of any use making an index on my_tags. For my app, this type of queries are used extensively.

Comment: Did you try the $all with your data and your code yourself? Did it work or did it not work? What's the point of your question? The behavior of $all is documented in depth - so why would we re-verify the functionality of $all for you? Try it with you data and then came back if you have a problem with $all...so what's your problem?

Comment: I did tried $all and it worked well enough. All I wanted to know was was there any advantage I get making an index over my_tags. And as far as documentation, I referred to http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Multikeys They have told about indexes on array, but i wanted to know whether it works with $all operator as well or not. Its not in docs for $all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> would it be of any use making an index on my_tags. For my app, this type of queries are used extensively.

Yes $all will use an index so it is still good to make one there however there are still optimisations that can be done for it: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5331 and https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1000

Normally the docs will only warn you of when something can not use an index.

Comment: still keep in mind that all documents which match the first tag are scanned for more details, so the first tag should be as selective as possible

Comment: @Dukeatcoding There is also another consideration here which is that $all works a lot like $in and in this respect it works better if the index is pre-sorted for the queries you make for it, I didn't add that to the answer originally

Comment: nice to know, i am working right now on a simlliar tag query and think about caching the results, do you have a pattern for that ?

Comment: @Dukeatcoding you mean for cardinal $all/$in? http://blog.mongolab.com/2012/06/cardinal-ins/ will help

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for the $all query is:

```
db.collection.find({'my_tags': {'$all': ['college', 'USA', 'engineering']}})
```

The documentation can be found at:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24all

Comment: Thanks, yeah I did that only, but I was interested in knowing the advantage of making an index over my_tags to speed up such queries if there is any.